# Final cadence appears as Em7 - Am (v7 - i in A minor). Name?

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, chord-progressions, cadence

I see an unusual cadence in the end of Debussy's Prelude of Pour le Piano.  It is v7 - i in A minor.  Is there an actual name for this?

[image]

---

(Chord Progression: Fmaj7 - Abaug7 - Gaug7 - C9 - Em7 - Am)

Comment: Would Ab7+ be a more apposite name? To augment a 7th takes it to the octave. And G would have D# if it was an aug, chord.

Comment: It would be a "pun" of the Gaug7 chord.  I wrote it as Gaug7 since it resolves to C9.

Comment: I dunno, @Tim, I always wrote augmented sevenths as C+7 (of course, not to be confused with Cadd9).

Comment: My point is that it's the 5th that's augmented, not the 7th. G7+ is spelled G B D# F.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the late 19th and early 20th centuries, composers experimented with many deviant final cadences. Most of them can be classed as variants of the existing formulas (authentic and plagal). This one is a variant of the authentic cadence, as I'm sure you noticed.

Comment: Is it a PAC or IAC?

Comment: The normal criteria for a PAC are that the chords are in root position and the tonic is in the melody. Both are true here, but since this is a minor dominant, it's debatable. The notion of a PAC precedes this kind of experimentation.